# CTRL-SHIFT-F2 loses all Byobu tabs

Tags: byobu

I love Byobu as it allows me to organize dozens of tabs with titles/paths/history. A handful are configured with `new-session`/`new-window` lines in my `~/.byobu/windows.tmux` and the rest I create ad-hoc depending on my current projects.

I often move tabs around with CTRL-SHIFT-F3 and CTRL-SHIFT-F4.
But if I mistakenly press CTRL-SHIFT-F2... all of my tabs are gone, causing me big sorrow.

Is there a way to undo that? The number at the lower left makes me think there might be a way to recover my tabs:
[image]

Or can I prevent CTRL-SHIFT-F2 from doing that?

Comment: @muru: Oh yes sorry, fixed! Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably would be the effect of this keybinding in `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux`:

```
bind-key -n C-S-F2 new-session
```

You could edit `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` and remove that keybinding:

```
unbind-key -n C-S-F2
```

Part of the default keybingings in tmux is (from [`man tmux`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tmux.1.html)):

```
s      Select a new session for the attached client
       interactively.
```

This is to be used with the prefix (default: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>), so you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to switch sessions.

By default, `tmux` also asks you to select from a list of open sessions if multiple sessions already exist when it is run:

```
~ byobu-tmux

Byobu sessions...

  1. tmux: 1: 2 windows (created Thu Jan 18 18:03:21 2018) [80x23]
  2. tmux: 2: 1 windows (created Thu Jan 18 18:03:24 2018) [80x23]
  3. tmux: 3: 1 windows (created Thu Jan 18 18:03:25 2018) [80x23]
  4. Create a new Byobu session (tmux)
  5. Run a shell without Byobu (/bin/zsh)

Choose 1-5 [1]:
```

Comment: I would rather keep my configuration within my home folder to ease OS reinstalls, so I added `unbind-key -n C-S-F2` to my `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux`, then closed Byobu and restarted it... but pressing CTRL-SHIFT-F2 still loses all tabs.

Comment: Maybe because I have `new-session`/`new-window` items in my `~/.byobu/windows.tmux`?  If I start xterm and type `byobu` in it, it just shows my configured windows, and the number in the lower left increases by 1.

Comment: Interesting! I edit my question to specify my particularity. If there were a way to "switch sessions" that would be a solution.

Comment: Try prefix-`s` (my prefix is Ctrl-A, so Ctrl-A, then `s` for me).

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge, how do I know what my "prefix" is?

Comment: The default is Ctrl-b. Do you have a `set -g prefix` in your keybindings somewhere?

Comment: wow, that worked! I get a list of sessions and am able to choose the first session where all of my dear tabs are! If you could add this to your answer that would be perfect :-)